# TF30063: You are not authorized to access after change from TFS2010 to TFS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I am working with `VS2012` and `TFS2012`. Before I have worked with `VS2010` and `TFS2010` and my 
credential was stored in the Credential Manager. Everything works fine and the shift to
`TFS2012` and `VS2012` was successful. The `VS2012` used the old settings in the Credential Manager.

The Admin has now changed my access to TFS with new username and pswd. After deleting my old
credentials and login via `VS2012` I get the Error
"`TF30063: You are not authorized to access...`"

Does anyone have an idea why this might be? Mabe are the permission on TFS2012 not correct?
The Admin said, that the permission are not changed and that they have the same settings as in
`TFS2012`.

Thanks in advance for every hint.

Best regards.

Comment: After a while searching on internet I found the solution under following link

[TFS 2012 – Issue: TF30063: You are not authorized to access and can’t trace permissions](http://nakedalm.com/tfs-2012-issue-tf30063-you-are-not-authorized-to-access-and-cant-trace-permissions/)

A global deny on TFS was defined for my account and the deny takes precedence over any other permission.

So I hope this will help you as it helped me.

Best regards.

Comment: I'm glad you found the answer. I suggest you move the answer from a comment to the answer - you may answer your own question. You'll get a badge for it, and people can find the answer and +1 it (you get points for that) :)

Comment: @GamblHarrenhal   - at this point maybe I should have the selected correct answer  ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks to Assaf Stone for the hint, to set my comment to a answer, so that everybody can find the solution.

So if anybody run into this issue, I hope this will help you:

"After a while searching on internet I found the solution under following link

[TFS 2012 – Issue: TF30063: You are not authorized to access and can’t trace permissions](http://nakedalm.com/tfs-2012-issue-tf30063-you-are-not-authorized-to-access-and-cant-trace-permissions/)

A global deny on TFS was defined for my account and the deny takes precedence over any other permission."

Best regards.

Answer (score 32):

Most people probably get this error with **visual studio**.  Example in **vs 2013**,  team explorer tab - click on

```
Select Team Projects   ->  Select a Team Foundation Server
```

You should get prompted to login.  If you had cancelled a login prompt, this is your chance to enter the credentials again.

**For Visual Studio 2012**

```
Team Explorer -> Connect to Team Projects (plug icon) -> Team Foundation Service -> Connect
```

**For Visual Studio 2015**

`Team Explorer --> Connect to Team Projects (plug icon) --> Manage Connections -->  Connect to Team Foundation Server`

Comment: Perhaps I now should have the selected answer   ;P

Answer (score 1):

**My fix was "clear the package cache"**, it can be found here: 
1 - Open VS 
2 - Go to Tools-> Options 
3 - Open "NuGet Package Manager" and select General 
4 - Click in the button: "clear the package cache"

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Simply *delete whole cache* in **Internet Explorer** did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I just received the "You are not authorized error" when trying to login via Visual Studio 2012. As @hfrmobile stated, going into Internet Explorer and clearing the entire cache worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try restarting TFSTray, not Team Foundation Server Best Practices Analyzer.

You will have to cycle through all the TFSTray options that you may have available.  In my case, I had to cycle TFSTray1 and TFSTray.

Windows (button) > type TFS > cycle throught the options, like the image below:

[image]

You could have issues with files that are locked.  You must use your explorer to changed from locked to write.

These steps worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. Close Visual Studio 2017
2. Open Visual Studio 2017 again

:-)